# First project rookie problems

Tags: html, css, navbar, project

I recently started trying to learn webdesign and I've already jumped into my first project. I've created a template in photoshop but I'm having trouble reproducing it in my visual studio code. **Any help would be awesome**. I've included my questions in the CSS comments. Also, not very relevant but, these past 3-4 days of this new learning experience have been great and very challenging! Would love some general coding tips if possible. Sorry for being an absolute noob. [My first project ideal outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpRDe.jpg)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #282828;
}
/* how can I make the navbar go a few pixels down? like in the photo */
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #cb209d;
}
/* can't make the searchbox go to the left side of the navbar :( */
.searchbox {
  float: left;
}
/* how am I supposed to center the social logos without using position: absolute? */
li {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  border-right: 1px solid #282828;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  color: #282828;
}
/*  Can't seem to fix these vertical dividers... I know, I'm a handful :/ */
li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
#u2b {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f77b4d6781.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <title>first project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- top navigation bar -->
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li id="u2b"><i class="fab fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
        <li>
          <input
            class="searchbox"
            type="text"
            name=""
            placeholder="Search me fam"
            id=""
          />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How can I make the navbar go a few pixels down? like in the photo?**
Margin or Paddings, how to decide? Consider your HTML layout.

**Can't make the search box go to the left side of the navbar?**
Research about [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and study your layout, it's [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) as well.

The last 3 answers can also be answered by good use of HTML layout and flexbox.

I would suggest you to research more about the display property as well

Once you've read the CSS Tricks Article, play around with [Flexbox Froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/)

Comment: I checked out the flexbox link you sent me and managed to fix my mistakes! Also, Flexbox Froggy was very useful, seems like I'm a visual learner :) project goes on! Thank you very much!!